# show result from PDO query every 10 seconds

Tags: javascript, php, pdo

Not sure if this is possible but here goes, I have a basic PDO query that stores the results in a array.

```
<?php
// configuration
$dbtype     = "";
$dbhost     = "";
$dbname     = "";
$dbuser     = "";
$dbpass     = "";
// database connection
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);
$title = 'PHP AJAX';
// query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM thankyou";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($title));
$q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
// fetch
while($r = $q->fetch()){
echo"<br>";
print_r ($r);
}
?>
```

Now the bit I can't get my head around, I have also never used JavaScript. Can I rotate through the results to show one at a time for 5-10 seconds then show another? It can be random or in order, I'm not fussed. I found this, which works, but can't figure out how to get the array into it. I am aware one is client side and one is server side.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var rotatingTextElement;
var rotatingText = new Array();
var ctr = 0;

function initRotateText() {
rotatingTextElement = document.getElementById("textToChange");
rotatingText[0] = rotatingTextElement.innerHTML; // store the content that's already on     the page
rotatingText[1] = "need to write PDO array here";
setInterval(rotateText, 5000);
}
function rotateText() {
ctr++;
if(ctr >= rotatingText.length) {
ctr = 0;
}
rotatingTextElement.innerHTML = rotatingText[ctr];
}
window.onload = initRotateText;
</script>
```

and this is were the results are shown

```
<span id="textToChange">this is were the result is displayed</span>
```

If I need to do it a totally different way, it's not a problem if someone can point me in the correct direction.

Comment: Use AJAX to poll data from the server with JavaScript. An easy way to use this with different browsers is by using jQuery (http://www.jquery.com/; although there are also other JS libraries). Here are the AJAX docs: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Thanks Reeno bit of reading to do.

Comment: Or is the array fixed and you only need to fetch it once and then display a random element from it every few seconds? The use `items[Math.floor(Math.random()*items.length)];` where `items` is an JS array

Answer (score 0):

If you're not so familiar with JavaScript, I also suggest using some JS library for the task. In fact, Prototype.js has a class exactly for this purpose: http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/ajax/Ajax/PeriodicalUpdater/index.html

A working example: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/prototype/prototype_ajax_periodicalupdater.htm

Answer (score 0):

i decided to use AJAX to call a seprate PHP page in the end and works fine this is the updated page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
      getStatus();
});
function getStatus() {
    $('div#status').load('thankyou.php')//Thankyou being the page the query is on
    setTimeout("getStatus()",5000);//refreshes every 5 seconds
}
</script>
```

The query itself is a standard PDO

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `thankyou` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Thanks for the pointers all.